# Connecting to IB TWS using IBpy

Tags: python, ibpy

I downloaded the standalone TWX for Mac OS X. Then I also installed IBpy through pip. I have the TWX open and I ran the following lines:

```
from ib.opt import ibConnection
con = ibConnection()
print(con.connect())
```

However, it prints False. What am I doing wrong? In TWX I have the localhost IP 127.0.0.1 as a trusted address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to check "enable activex and socket clients" in the API settings.
There may be a bug in newer versions 950-952 where you don't specify 127.0.0.1, but instead check the box where it says "allow connections from localhost only".  I haven't tested that, but have read about it.

If you use IB gateway, "enable socket clients" isn't required as the only way to use it is with an API.  Note that gateway is port 4001 by default.  Use `con = ibConnection(port=4001,clientId=123)`

You're connecting with clientId 0, you could use `con = ibConnection(123)` for example to use a different clientId.

Don't forget to call con.disconnect() to close the connection or the server won't allow you to re-connect using that id.

add: here's the bug I read about at IB-API yahoo user group.

> But as soon as I uncheck ‘Allow connections from localhost only’, it
>   won’t accept connections from any address, not even local ones (ie
>   even with 127.0.0.1 as a Trusted IP address).

Comment: Brian, I tried enabling activex and socket clients, opening IB gateway and running the code, as well as using a different client ID. It still gave me False. Any other ideas?

Comment: don't add a trusted address 127.0.0.1, just check the "allow connections from localhost only".

Comment: I'm using windows 7 64 and I can't replicate the bug I read about.  Mine connects with localhosts only and if I add 127.0.0.1 as a trusted address.

Comment: Brian, I can't find the  "allow connections from localhost only" option under Configure->API... I'm using the TWX demo 1.0

Comment: I'm not sure actually what I did was just restarting TWS, restarting terminal, deleting 127.0.0.1 and re-adding it, etc. And somehow it worked lol..